# How can I get 1 value per key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am aware that dictionaries should already have a single value per key, but in my case I made a dictionary from a csv file (which can NOT be modified in any way). This csv file has 2 columns and instead of getting the first column as keys and the second as values, I get the first row as keys (so 2 keys) and everything else as values. Is there any way to modify this in python and get the first column as keys and the second as values?

The code is basically:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dict = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: How can we modify your code if we don't know how it looks like?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pandas? If so, the following will work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

your_dict = df.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict()
```

This assumes your columns are named A and B, where A is the key and B is the value.

Comment: I tried this but I get KeyError: "None of [A] are in the columns. Which is odd because it is indeed in the columns.

Comment: You need to plug in your own column names instead of A and B.

Comment: Yes, I know, I put A for better understanding on the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `pandas`, just read the file into `dict()` (the built-in `dict`, not the override from your code)

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    d = dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in file.readlines())
```

Comment: Tried this. I got the following error: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required.

Comment: @dandan Is the csv file is comma separated? do you have 2 values in all rows?

Comment: Yes it is, now I see the problem. The file has let's say 2 "sectors" (like 2 groups of different data). The sector I want to work with (the second one) has 2 values in all rows, but the previous sector has more than 2. I guess the best would be create the dictionary just for the sector I want to work with, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @dandan I'm not really sure what you mean by "sectors", but you can probably split every row by some condition to separate them.

Comment: With "sectors" I mean I have 2 groups of different data basically, and I need to by-pass the first group. I will try, thank you!